# REGEX - How to find any char followed by ? followed by a char

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex in Python that finds all instances of the following:

Hi this isn?t a test.

**I'm trying to find the n?t**

So I need any alphanumeric (including whitespace), but then after the question mark just alpha/numeric (no spaces).

So far I have

```
r'.[?]\w'
```

which appears to work, but I'm not sure if I'm missing anything.

Comment: You may use: `r'[a-zA-Z0-9 ]\?[a-zA-Z0-9]'`

Comment: Only that `.` is **any** character and not necessarily an alphanumeric... Not sure if that's what you mean though? (You can also use `\?` for a literal ? instead of putting it in a character class)

Comment: So for, it looks good. Have you tried it against some data, that would be your next step toward seing if you are missing anything.

Comment: Thanks, tried it against a large data set and was expecting more hits. That's why I wasn't sure if it was matching everything. Will what I have, find multiple instances in the line or only the first? Data is large and hard to find every instance

Comment: @fpolig01 What are your exact rules? Alphanumeric does not include "whitespace", it is `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Please explain what you need to find, and unless you do it, no one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Anubhava's r'[a-zA-Z0-9 ]\?[a-zA-Z0-9]' is what you want. However, you might also consider doing a separate search for question marks that aren't followed by a capital letter, just in case these question marks are replacing characters like ' in other places:

```
r'\?\s+[a-z]'
```

The regex above (and Anubhava's) is using a backslash to escape the question mark. Your way (square brackets) will work fine too.